# Compare format string to actual string python

Tags: python, string, integer

I have the following format, as a string variable

```
format = '$<amount> has been received from <user>'
```

How would I check if another string fits the format, for example:

```
message = '$50 has been received from Hugh'
```

I'd like to check that the message exactly fits the format, and save the data, in this case `50` and `Hugh` in two separate variables.
I checked RegEx on a few websites such as W3Schools and PyPi, but couldn't find anything that fits what it is I'm trying to do.

Comment: You can use [next](https://regex101.com/r/U3JxTk/1) regular expression in [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match): `re.match(r"\$\d+ has been received from (?:Hugh|John|Matt)", s)`.

Comment: I've never used RegEx before, would it be possible for you to show me how I'd write that as code?

Comment: I've added link to website where you can find detailed explanation of this regular expression. Also there's link to docs of function I've used with some explanation. Check them out ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
message = '$50 has been received from Hugh'

import re
regex = re.compile(r'\$(\d+) has been received from (\w+)')
amount, user = regex.findall(message)[0]
print(amount, user) # 50, Hugh
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Works perfectly! Just wondering, is it possible to run an if statement to check that the message meets the format, before I try and extract the data from it?

Comment: @Hugh67945, If you want entire string to match pattern, it's better to use `re.match()` instead. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match): "If the whole *string* matches this regular expression, return a corresponding [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects). Return `None` if the string does not match the pattern.". I recommend you to read about [Truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). As it's written in docs, `None` is always false, so you can test result of `match()` directly.

Comment: Do you know how it would be possible for me to turn <amount> and <user> into `(\d+)` and `(\w+)`? Like, as in, have the Python code do it for me? Cus the message format changes sometimes

Comment: @OlvinRoght <<<

Comment: @Hugh67945, `\d` means *digit*, `+` means *one or more*; `\w` means *word character*. You want to translate your pattern to regular expression, which could be done using `re.sub(r"\<\w+\>", r"(\\w+)", re.escape(fmt))`. Your format doesn't contain any information about data types so I used `\w` which include ascii letters both in upper and lower cases, digits and underline.

Comment: @OlvinRoght ran into a small problem. Doesn't work when the username is two words. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Hugh67945, you kinda misunderstood how does this website work. You've got an answer to your question and some tips in comments, but it doesn't mean that you hire me or any other user to do your work.

Comment: regex = re.compile(r'\$(\d+) has been received from (.*)')